# How to find a partial match based on a number in mongodb?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document that has some IDs (not objectID) that are numbers. There are also times when no parentId will be passed to the function.
Currently I have

```
return ExampleModel.find({
  $or: [
    {
      parentId: new RegExp(exampleDtoSearch.parentId.toString()),
    },
    { /*other things to search*/ } 
]
})
```

The error I am getting if I hand in a parentId is " AssertionError: The expression evaluated to a falsy value. "

And the error I get if there is no id is that it can't do toString on undefined.

How do I do a regex (or something similar) to do partial matches for numbers in mongodb/mongoose?

Comment: What does mongoose have to do with this?

Comment: I know that some times mongoose will implement things differently than plain mongodb, so I wanted to provide that context.

Answer (score -2):

Use [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/).

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.foo.insert({a:111})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

MongoDB Enterprise > db.foo.aggregate([{$addFields:{a_s:{$convert:{input:'$a',to:'string'}}}},{$match:{a_s:/1/}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fb571b0886cb08b7890f27f"), "a" : 111, "a_s" : "111" }
```

Comment: can you explain this? or how i would use this with a variable?

Comment: Read the documentation for all operators involved, if something is not clea'r ask specific questions. If you are asking how to use javascript variables, create a new question for that.

Comment: I'm asking how I would use this with a parameter instead of a hard coded value and I'm asking how to do this in JS, not using the mongo command line. Thanks!